# Flutter with native Kotlin rebuild after every change in MainActivity.kt?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, notifications

We are currently working on a Flutter app that uses native Kotlin to display custom notifications. To do this we constantly change things in the MainActivity.kt file.
For every change we want to test, we need to delete the build and rebuild the application from scratch. Simply re-running the debug does not work. As we are new with both Flutter and Kotlin we were wondering whether there is a better way (not having to completely rebuild the app) to test changes we make in the MainActivity.kt file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*Simply re-running the debug does not work.*" - could you expand on that? What exactly doesn't work? What kind of errors are you encountering?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Fureeish re-running the debug will not result in any errors. Any changes we made in the MainActivity.kt file will simply not show. We have to rebuild (remove the build folder and start the debug again) the application before the changes show up.

Comment: I faced the same issue, every change on native code needs to be rebuilt :(